# Fixing software center catalog

Tags: software-center

I'm new to Ubuntu, it looks like it is better than Windows. Last day I tried to install Kget (the download manager) but during the process my computer suddenly stopped working. So I had to switch it off. After I logged into Ubuntu again I can't install any program. The Ubuntu Software Center says:

```
Items cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired.
Do you want to repair it now?
```

After I clicked repair it says (after few seconds):

```
Package operation fails - The installation or removal of a software package failed
```

I've tried several times, but the same problem occurred. Can anyone tell me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open a terminal and try this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It will fix all broken packages. after this you can install any s/w you want.

Answer (score 24):

To fix broken packages in Ubuntu, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

> If the problem still exist, then edit `dpkg status` file
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```
>
> Find the package in question, and remove everything that has anything to do with it >and save the file.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu fix](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution)</sup>

Comment: Is editing the dpkg status file a pretty safe thing? Like, will I be running a large risk of screwing up my whole system?

Comment: If you delete the package in question, should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04.1,
I had a problem with broken packages, and when trying all the common things like `apt-get -f install`, I got an error, something like `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Instead of reinstalling and spending hours setting things up, I got my hands dirty, and eventually fixed. Here's how:

1. Synaptic uses `apt-get` underhood. Go use that `apt-get` at console. Figure out what commands are used by Synaptic, or which to use.
2. `apt-get` uses `dpkg` internally. If it tells `dpkg` ended with an error, try to do the operation with `dpkg` directly, you'll see the actual error.
3. `dpkg` stores it's metadata in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`. In my case, it had problems with `samba-libs`, installing (corrupted archive) or removing (metadata missing -> saying it's not installed). So I deleted the metadata. Then ran `dpkg --clear-avail`. Then downloaded the library, put to the place instead of the corrupted file. Then `apt-get update`.  Then `dpkg --install <path-to-lib>`. And then it started working.