# What exactly does sudo apt-get -f install do?

Tags: apt, sudo

I have seen it before. I am just wondering what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From `man apt-get`:

```
   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This
       option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT
       to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to
       completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when
       running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package
       dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency
       structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually
       means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
       packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Comment: A you can thank the lord for it. When you have a broken package its like having a rock inside your shoe... and you are in a marathon... with bears riding sharks riding huge spiders. But thanks to this broken stuff gets fixed.

Comment: In the occasional situation where `sudo apt-get -f install` is not, by itself, sufficient to fix broken packages, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/183625/22949).

Comment: Just as an addition - if you change your mind about the `package` that resulted in the unmet dependencies, then simply do `sudo apt-get remove package` to get rid of the unmet dependency error and not install the packages that fix the break.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I found it very useful. I ran a dpkg command to install a couple of .deb packages, but the install failed because some dependencies were missing.

I then ran

```
apt-get -f install
```

and it installed exactly the dependencies that were needed. I was then able to re-run my dpkg command and everything worked.