# I get the same updates every time

Tags: updates, vlc

I see that on my Ubuntu 12.04lts machine, I get the same updates every time. The updates are for vlc player. It repeats at least once a day. Is something stuck or does it do that. I have installed vlc to the latest version for linux via commands I found on ask ubuntu that I have on terminal. O, and I see no other updates, but these.

Comment: Sounds like you added a daily build PPA. If you have further detaild to add, go ahead.

Comment: yes, I have, 4 of them for vlc. This wouldn't cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the four repositories,then uninstall existing vlc by running,

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

and then run the below commands on terminal to install a vlc stable release,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: it give me problems, I can't put vlc back. it says: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but does nothing. It says:0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-nox`

Comment: Thanks, but I get this when I run the command suggested:  Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: try these commands on terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: I've tried it and it still won't work, I get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.8+git20131130+r49148+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-nox libvlccore5 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse`

Comment: I've tried it, but still get the same error as above. Any other way to get the broken packages out of the way or to get them fixed first so that I can install vlc without any problems?

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/122105/how-do-i-locate-and-remove-broken-packages-that-i-have-installed