# How to fix or re-install the broken packages resulting from updates installation?

Tags: package-management, updates, kubuntu, kde

I recently installed Kubuntu 14.04 and I installed available updates. Then, I got a black screen with mouse pointer visible. I lost my desktop. However I got to terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Then I ran `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. It gave me my desktop back.

Unfortunately, I found that some applications were broken and missing such as muon, dolphin, kontact, ktp-contactlist, etc. I tried [several tips about package and apt commands](http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/05/how-to-fix-broken-packages-using.html). Nothing worked. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` did not solve the problem. Nothing was upgraded.

I could successfully installed **dolphin** by running `sudo apt-get install dolphin`. But I failed with `muon` and `kontact`. The below is what I tried for `muon`.

```
sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install muon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
muon : Depends: libmuonprivate2 (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: muon-updater but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `libmuonprivate2`, but it depends on `software-properties-kde`.

```
sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libmuonprivate2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmuonprivate2 : Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `software-properties-kde`, but it depends on `python3-software-properties`.

```
sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-kde
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
software-properties-kde : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.92.36) but 0.92.37.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `python3-software-properties`, but it seems update-to-date.

```
sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-software-properties is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also tried to [locate and re-install broken packages using **Synaptic Package Manager**](https://askubuntu.com/q/122105/177906), but no luck. Applying the changes gave me this dialog:

```
Could not apply changes!
Fix broken packages first.
```

"Fix broken packages" gave me this dialog:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would you try `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo apt-get -f install` (without package)?

Comment: @ByteCommander `apt-get check` nothing gave me. `apt-get -f install` gave me `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `python3-software-properties` but it is not easy to say what. Could you try to purge it and then install `muon`?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Oh yes! `apt-get purge python3-software-properties` and `apt-get install muon` reinstalled **muon** successfully. It also solved another problem of `kdeplasma-addons` re-installation. If you add an answer for this, I will accept it. It will be great if you could add the reason of `purge`. However, it is difficult to fix the packages which have a lot dependencies such as `kontact`. [Please check what I did with `kontact`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QsP0Ns6dWeJL4M_fyxPxzTzTlWlV6xqKmMjDNEizTsw/edit?usp=sharing). Is there any better way to solve this.

Comment: I still get the same error when I run both the commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `python3-software-properties` package or some of its configuration files, that might be providing inaccurate information to `apt-get`. I thus suggest you to purge this package:

`sudo apt-get purge python3-software-properties`

And then install `muon`:

`sudo apt-get install muon`

This later command will force a fresh install of `python3-software-properties` and any other packages `muon` may depend upon.

For more details on `apt-get purge`, I suggest [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/231568/177437).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it the only way to figure out the unmet dependencies deeply down one by one? Is there any other quicker and easier way to fix those broken packages?

Comment: This one by one drill down is indeed the only way I know of in a case like this. Most of the time `apt-get -f install` does it on its own.

Comment: Yes, `-f` did not work for me. Even in **Muon Package Manager**, there is no broken packages listed :(

Comment: I get the unmet dependencies error again

Answer (score 0):

After... months! of having broken packages in my 14.10 Ubuntu, and not finding any way of fixing the problem (I've tried all the solutions you can find in the first 10 pages of google results), I accidentally found how to solve it for real: 
Just go to the "recovery mode" in the boot menu, **enable the network connection** and run the "fix broken packages" option. It will take a while, but it totally fixes the problem.