# How to install standalone LINE or LINE plugin for Pidgin in Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, plugins, pidgin, source-packages

I want to use [LINE](http://line.me) in my Kubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately [LINE has no official release for Linux](http://line.me/en/download). I found some unconfirmed sources of installing LINE in Linux. I tried LINE with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), but it did not work as expected.

[Pidgin with LINE plugin](https://wiki.debian.org/Pidgin) is another source I found. According to it, some prerequisites have to be built and installed:

- apache-thrift
- purple-line

There are several dependencies before installing **apache-thrift**. Hopefully they will work without breaking any lib configuration in my Kubuntu (as [I have experienced with broken packages problem in my system](https://askubuntu.com/q/583763/177906)).

The main problem is the installation of [purple-line from github source](https://github.com/mvirkkunen/purple-line). I could not see any source code in the repo except README.md. I don't think that it will work with `make` and `make install`.

Is there any safe and correct installation of LINE in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Line4pidgin needs `apache-thrift` and `purple-line`.

Compile `apache-thrift`:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get install bison libboost-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libevent-dev libcommons-lang-java php5-dev python-dev python-twisted libbit-vector-perl php5-dev php5-cli libglib2.0-dev
# cd /tmp
# wget https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/thrift/0.9.3/thrift-0.9.3.tar.gz
# tar xzvf thrift-0.9.3.tar.gz
# cd thrift-0.9.3
# ./configure
# make
# make install
# ln -s /usr/local/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.so /usr/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.so
```

Next, compile and install `purple-line`:

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /tmp
# wget https://github.com/mvirkkunen/purple-line/archive/master.zip
# unzip master.zip
# cd purple-line-master
# make
# make install
```

I hope after compiling and installing you will see `~/.purple/plugins/libline.so` and can choose LINEacc in Pidgin.

Comment: It is what I mentioned in [one of the web links in my question](https://wiki.debian.org/Pidgin) and it is the main problem, isn't it?