# Installing kubuntu-desktop failed for unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, kde

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04. I lost my desktop and got error `unable to launch "/usr/bin/startkde" X sesssion - "/usr/bin/startkde" not found; falling back to default session`. I found [a possible fix in a post](https://plus.google.com/+SwapnilBhartiya/posts/MPFp8zScFqF) and I followed the instruction by entering the terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+F1`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

The last command results unmet dependencies problem and I got stuck.

[image]

#### [UPDATE]

The result of `apt-cache policy kubuntu-desktop kde-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook` looks like

[image]

I encountered [the similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/583763/177906) before that I could successfully install the desktop, but I think this case is little different from it.

Comment: Can you add the output of `apt-cache policy kubuntu-desktop kde-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook` (you could add more of the listed packages to the command, but that should be enough as a start) to your question, please? Plain, code-formatted text is preferred over screen photos though, if possible.

Comment: @ByteCommander Please check the update for `apt-cache` in the question. I can't copy and paste the texts as I can't use mouse in the terminal without desktop. The screens had to be taken by mobile camera.

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing packages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuring out the unmet dependencies drilling down one by one solved the problem.

```
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
apt-get install kubuntu-workspace
apt-get install kubuntu-workspace-bin
apt-get install plasma-desktop
apt-get install plasma-dataengines-workspace
apt-get install kdepim-runtime
apt-get install akonadi-server
apt-get install akonadi-backend-mysql
```

When I tried the above commands one-by-one, the dependency requirements stopped at `akonadi-backend-mysql`. I noticed mysql 5.6 was removed during `akonadi-backend-mysql` installation. Just before my desktop lost, I upgraded mysql 5.5 to 5.6. Probably it made the desktop broken.

Finally I successfully got my desktop back by running these commands, but I lost mysql 5.6.

```
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop --fix-missing
```

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/862733/177906

Answer (score 2):

It seems you was upgrading kubuntu, but then somehow lost connection in the middle of process.

The plausible fix is to reinstalling `kubuntu-desktop` package, although the command you run is right. Have you tried manually installing the missing packages that listed on `it is not going to be installed`?

```
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook software-properties-kde kadressbook apturl-kde apport-kde akregator kde-telepathy kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kmail knotes kontact korganizer muon-discover muon-notifier plasma-runner-telepathy-contact plasma-widgets-addons usb-creator-kde
```

Comment: Manually appending all listed packages to the install command is what I would have suggested next, too. You should try that @Sithu.

Comment: @ByteCommander Please check my answer below and [my follow-up question](http://askubuntu.com/q/862733/177906).