# How to install safely mysql 5.6 against akonadi-backend-mysql in Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, mysql, dependencies

This results from [installing kubuntu-desktop failed for unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862365/installing-kubuntu-desktop-failed-for-unmet-dependencies). I guess I lost my kubuntu desktop after mysql 5.6 installation. I recovered the desktop back by installing [kubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/misc/kubuntu-desktop)  and [akonadi-backend-mysql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/misc/akonadi-backend-mysql) which depends on mysql 5.5.

When I got the desktop back, the previously installed MySQL 5.6 was gone and these two files are not found in the directory `/var/run/mysqld/`.

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I still have the configuration files

```
/etc/mysql/my.conf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/my5.6.conf
```

and the databases in the data directory

```
/var/lib/mysql/
```

I will have to install MySQL 5.6, but my concern is that akonadi-backend-mysql may not work with 5.6. I found [that kind of bug reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/akonadi/+bug/1330180). Here are some of my details:

```
sudo apt-cache depends akonadi-backend-mysql
[sudo] password for sithu: 
akonadi-backend-mysql
 |Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5
  Depends: mariadb-server-core-5.5
 |Depends: mysql-client-core-5.5
  Depends: mariadb-client-core-5.5
  Depends: libqt4-sql-mysql
  Recommends: akonadi-server
  Breaks: akonadi-server
  Replaces: akonadi-server


sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-cache policy akonadi-backend-mysql
akonadi-backend-mysql:
  Installed: 1.12.1-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.12.1-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.1-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.12.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages


sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-core-5.6 : Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.5 but 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This results `unmet dependencies: mysql-client-core-5.6 : Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.5 but 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed`.

So, my question is

1. Is it safe to install MySQL 5.6 against `akonadi-backend-mysql`?
2. How to install it without breaking my desktop again?

My distro is Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
sithu@sithu-kubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                         
Distributor ID: Ubuntu                                                                                                
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS                                                                                    
Release:        14.04                                                                                                 
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) 10.1 with features from MySQL 5.6 & 5.7 and everything is going fine.

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```