# How to list broken packages in console

Tags: command-line, package-management

When I try to google how to do this, all the results I get are "**How to fix broken packages**".

Could you give me a hint how to only list them in the console one by one?

Comment: I am not sure how to find broken packages, but if you suspect about one and don't remember the specific name, try `dpkg --list` to see all the stuff you have installed. Be careful! Do not delete random stuff that you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can list broken packages :

```
dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

**r** state (on the third field) means: reinst-required (package broken, reinstallation required)

[dpkg fields explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)

Comment: There is no r state, but R flag. Package may be broken even without the flag.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that nobody has recommended this:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

also for more info try

```
apt-get --help
```

Answer (score 6):

To get the list of partially installed packages (with architecture information) preceded by their states, one by line, run

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E ^.[^nci]
```

See `man dpkg-query` for information about the states etc. (I [suppose](https://askubuntu.com/q/915005/21005) the Reinst-required i.e. R flag can not appear with states n, c or i. If it could, the extended regular expression in grep command should be modified.)

Answer (score 1):

I did a `dist-upgrade` which completed, but had puked some errors during the process. So I wanted to validate the errors weren't merely just noise.

`apt-get check -v` returned **NO** faults.

**HOWEVER**: Suspicious the previous command didn't provide correct feedback, I next executed:

`dpkg -C`

This command **DID** validate the errors

Given the above experience, I'd suggest not to take the output of `apt-get check -v` as the gospel everything is clean...