# Dependency Loop When Trying to Install Firefox Xvfb

Tags: 16.04, apt, server, firefox, xvfb

I am installing firefox xvfb on 16.04.4 (server) so that I can use the Firefox driver with Selenium in order to do screen grabs of our websites using Python.  Unfortunately, I am in some sort of install dependency loop.

when I install firefox xvfb, I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
...
firefox : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
```

So my next logical step is to install the dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                   libwayland-egl1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I searched AU to find how to search for broken packages, coming across [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772653/how-to-list-broken-packages-in-console) which instructs me to run the command:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

Unfortunately, this returns nothing.

I am at a loss on what to do next , I have:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update –fix-missing
```

as well attempted using aptitude to install all of the same things.

Not sure if this is related but something similar has happened before when trying to use  pip3 install.  Eventually I just gave up, and stuck to python 2.7 for this project.  I don't think that it is a firefox xvfb problem, as I also tried installed google-chrome-stable with no success.

Any help or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Output of *apt-cache policy firefox xvfb:*

```
firefox:
  Installed: 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 64.0~b13+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
     64.0~b13+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xvfb:
  Installed: 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Check your repositories - please add output of `apt-cache policy firefox xvfb` to the question. It seems that you have missed *xenial-updates* pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to purge Mozilla's PPA:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

to resolve dependency errors.

Also please note that official Ubuntu repository has [Firefox 63.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&searchon=names&keywords=firefox) which is not too different from 64...