# Computer suddenly shuts down while doing specific things

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, minecraft

Whenever I run this command my computer suddenly shuts off

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It also shuts off when trying to change between the open source driver to nvidia driver. Also, when playing minecraft, creating a new world, waiting a couple seconds, and then my computer will suddenly shut off.

I'm on 16.04.1 LTS.

Specs:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23128825/plain/

Comment: Hardware specs?

Comment: Is there a way where I can copy paste all my specs?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/820507/edit), or use http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Specs:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23128825/

Comment: @CelticWarrior i posted the specs for you

Comment: You're still using the open source driver *noveau* for your Nvidia graphics indeed.  So, a few questions come to mind: 1. How are you trying to install nvidia proprietary drivers? 2. What problem led you to do *dpkg --configure -a*? and finally 3. Is it really shutting down or is just the video?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I install the graphics drivers this way: http://bit.ly/2cdbYmC
When I type dpkg --configure -a the computer suddenly shuts down completely

the reason i typed dkg --configure -a is because when i try to do sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* it tells me to do that command

Comment: You don't need the PPA. 16.04 has the required driver version for your card. I suggest you remove the PPA (with ppa-purge), reboot and then System Settings > Software properties > Additional drivers (tab) and select the recommended version and apply. Does it still shuts down?

Comment: Alright, so I'm about to type 

sudo apt install ppa-purge

then im going to type sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

 When i try to type apt install ppa-purge, it gives me this

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I typed in sudo dpkg --configure -a and then once again my computer suddenly shuts down.

Comment: Well, I'm going to be brutally honest: If it was me, I would be reinstalling Ubuntu already.

Comment: Alright, I will do that.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Alright so I just re-installed Ubuntu, so when I go to Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers, it says I'm using X.Org X Server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source) I have 4 NVIDIA drivers to chose from, which one should I choose? I have tried multiple times now from fresh ubuntu installations and no matter what I choose, it will completely shutdown when it is almost 70-80 percent done. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Choose the one with "recommend" or "tested".

Comment: There is no NVIDIA driver that says recommend.

Comment: Also there's a good chance that either the graphics chip/car and/or RAM are busted. Shutdowns are never normal and seldom software related.

Comment: Alright, so I have done what you have said multiple times before on fresh ubuntu installations, and whenever it is 70-80% done the computer will crash and shutdown.  and when I reboot and go to the screen it will say i have the nvidia driver selected I know it isn't selected correctly because when I go to settings -> details the Graphics section will say Intel sandybridge mobile whereas on my dads computer it will say his Graphics card (in his case Geforce 620M

Comment: @CelticWarrior so basically i'm stuck with the open source driver? also do you think its more likely the graphics chip is busted or the ram is busted?

Comment: Honestly, even if I was testing the machine myself I wouldn't be able to tell without further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of old joke. Guy says to doctor, "it hurts when I do this!"  Doctor says "stop doing that."

You probably have several broken packages. Dpkg is trying to alter something required by the display. 'dpkg' is a blunt instrument. It cannot pull in additional packages to get what it needs. You need fix the breakage before configuring. minecraft is probably tickling same breakage.

For me, it is usually better to remove broken packages (later to reinstall) than to repair/reconfigure: [How do I locate and remove Broken Packages that I have installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122105/how-do-i-locate-and-remove-broken-packages-that-i-have-installed)

For years, I've not needed to run that dpkg configure you are trying. Needing that is a sign you have done something incorrectly, something deeper is wrong for which you need a light fingered solution. Best answer is to remove the incompletely installed trouble packages,e.g nvidia

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Importance of 'purge' is to get rid of settings. Watch the errors when that runs. You may need to reinstall something that was damaged. (Bad news. If packages required by the currently running graphics display must be fiddled, your display may crash. You might need to log out, then try Alt-Ctl-F1 to get to VT1 and try apt-get commands there. Reboot from VT1.)

DO not reinstall nvidia yet. Check for broken packages.

Oh, and... I am a doctor.  Quit playing minecraft. Run programs that are safer.

Before running something that has failed, open terminal and run it with ldd, as in

```
ldd minecraft
```

ldd shows all shared libraries a program needs, and which are missing. Run that on a program that works, you'll see what I mean.

Admittedly, most of us don't see such exciting trouble as you see. It will get better, I expect. Funny coincidence. Reading your message crashed my Android tablet.