# Can't remove a broken package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122105/how-do-i-locate-and-remove-broken-packages-that-i-have-installed) where it is explained how to remove a borken package using Syanptic.

I tried this solution, but when I find the borken package I can't remove it.

[image]

Here, when I right-click the package, only "Unmark" option is available, the "Remove" is shaded and can't click it. Same for any other option but Unmark.

Also, I came to this situation when used the "Mark to install", otherwise the Broken dependencies are not even shown because there is none.

How could I remove the broken package so I can finally install it?

When I try to use `sudo apt-get install r-base` I got the following error:

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 r-base : Depende: r-base-core (>= 3.3.3-1xenial0) pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: r-recommended (= 3.3.3-1xenial0) pero no va a instalarse
          Recomienda: r-base-html pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Maybe somewhere there is the problem?

Comment: Looks like the package is marked as to be removed already and all you have to do is to click on `Aplicar`.

Comment: It is marked to Install. When I click `Aplicar` it says I should first solve broken packages.

Comment: Would be good to know which version of Ubuntu you use. The recent version of r-base in the xenial repository (main,universe) is `3.2.3-4`. You are trying to install version `3.3..3-1xenial0`. Have you added any ppa (`sudo add-apt-repository`)?

Comment: Not that I know. I had followed instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2

Comment: This tutorial let you add a ppa (`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'`)

Comment: then, so did I. Sorry for my little knowledge of Ubuntu

Comment: If you can live with version `3.2.3-4` I'd recommend to remove the ppa (`sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'`) first and install from the official repository with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install r-base`.

Comment: It seems like the problem might be I have Ubuntu 14.04. I used https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04 and everything went well

Comment: Congratulations, you solved the problem. Please consider writing an answer by yourself and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it happened that I was using Ubuntu 14.04 but following instructions for Ubuntu 16.04.

After finding and following the correct instructions it had been solved.

Instructions followed:
16.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2
14.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Errare humanum est!