# VLC not able to be install via apt because some 'libgles1' problem, how to fix it?

Tags: apt, dependencies, vlc, libraries

After using my package manager to install VLC

```
apt-get install vlc
```

I get this message

```
root@DerPCmitDerGtx1050:/home/gtx1050# apt-get install  vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
            libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/166949/665251 Try this, this should work

Comment: I tried the synaptic approach, but when I select the "broken"-category no package is listed