# Broken packages, synaptic and Libre Office broken, when upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, version

I upgraded to version 12.04 this morning. Has caused broken packages which I cannot undo because it has caused brakages in my synaptic package manager.

I cannot use Libre office writer and every time I enter calc, math, writer etc, it automatically reverts to 'calc' I use writer in virtually all my applications and run my business with it.

Is there any way to fix these breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried-

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Run this code in terminal, it is used to fix broken packages. [What exactly does sudo apt-get -f install do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do)