# Problems with Ubuntu 13.04 upgrading

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, on the top marging to the left of the language indicator, it appears a red circle with a white line in it, and I cannot open the software updater to solve this problem.

The performance is normal, however from time to time I have to restart my netbook.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Este sitio funciona solamente en inglés. Podés usar una traducción robótica, como la de [PROMPT](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=es) o la de Google. Escribí tanto tu pregunta original en español como la traducción. Todas las respuestas las obtendrás invariablemente en inglés. -- This site works in English only. You can use a robotic translation service, such as [PROMPT's](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=en) or Google's. Write your question in Spanish and paste the translated text. All answers will invariably be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

Read [What exactly does sudo apt-get -f install do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58378/58950)

In the occasional situation where `sudo apt-get -f install` is not, by itself, sufficient to fix broken packages, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/183625/58950). <sub>(This sentence has been shamelessly plagiarised from a comment by [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) in the Q&A linked above.)</sub>