# I run a "outdated" command that may have harmed Ubuntu!

Tags: command-line, midi

I run a possibly dangerous and unpredictable command, please I need help in reverting wichever changes it may have done. Without reinstalling Ubuntu if possible. I need to make sure I haven't made bad compatibility issues installing old software. Because if that's the case, I may have many bugs and problems in the future, and this will be the cause.

The situation:
I was trying to fix MIDI problems. [So I found this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting), found this command and run it:

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

I gave root permission after asked. And the dangerous part is that even if the command is suggested on a Ubuntu help page, the page itself **says it's outdated at the top and should not be used** various times.

This is the official prompt (and starts with the command typed). Can you tell me if it has damaged my machine? I'm thinking that it may hve installed very old softwares, because the instruction was in the tutorial wich was not recomended. How can I get back to before? Or simply there is not a problem?

```
qwerty@qwerty-RV420-RV520-RV720-E3530-S3530:~$ sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "linux-ubuntu-modules-3.19.0-42-generic"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "linux-ubuntu-modules-3.19.0-42-generic"
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2 linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic 
  linux-sound-base 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.427 kB/18,2 MB of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Get: 1 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 [327 kB]
Get: 2 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main alsa-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 [151 kB]
Get: 3 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main alsa-utils amd64 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2 [933 kB]
Get: 4 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main linux-sound-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 [14,5 kB]
Fetched 1.427 kB in 6s (215 kB/s)                                               
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 198306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libasound2_1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasound2:amd64 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) over (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic_3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic (3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1) over (3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic...
P: Writing config for Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1...
P: Writing config for Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) over (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-utils_1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-utils (1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2) over (1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-sound-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) over (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libasound2:amd64 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic (3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic...
P: Writing config for Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1...
P: Writing config for Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4
Found Debian GNU/Linux (8.2) on /dev/sda5
done
Setting up linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up alsa-utils (1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

Comment: I'd try `sudo apt-get -f install` just in case. It can't hurt, and it usually sorts out any version incompatibilities. See this page to understand the command if you don't already: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `aptitude --help`

> purge        - Remove packages and their configuration files.
>
> reinstall    - Download and (possibly) reinstall a currently installed package.

So, what you have done is that, you have purged the packages that are in your command and reinstalled them. So, far so good, but there was just one part in your command that might have caused some problems. The part of the command where it said:

```
linux-image-`uname -r`
```

deleted your active kernel and then re-installed it. Though its most unlikely to happen but in extreme cases it might cause you some problems. Apart from that everything is ok.

**From your output it seems that there were no errors and everything is as it should have been.**

If you are still unsure - check the versions and everything else of the purged packages, using the following command:

```
apt-cache policy linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried that it installed older versions. In the prompt it says it could not find some packages.

Comment: From which command???

Comment: No. I read now the prompt. It says ((Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "linux-ubuntu-modules-3.19.0-42-generic" )) but ok. It's all right I didn't say anything.

Comment: Don't worry it wasn't removed because it wasn't installed in the first place. Nothing happened with that package don't worry. See this: `Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched linux-ubuntu-modules-3.19.0-42-generic"`

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what to see, that's what I wrote in the previous comment. You want me to actually see that in fact it wasn't found, ergo not installed?