# Unmet dependencies for gcc-5-multilib and libc6-dev-x32 when trying to install Steam in 16.10

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, steam, 16.10

Below are the results of trying to install Steam in 16.10.

```
sudo apt-get install steam
[sudo] password for micah:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I solve these unmet dependencies?

Comment: Please explain in words what the problem is, what triggered it, what are trying to install, etc. and please do not use screenshots for error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam)

Answer (score 4):

Steam has two i386 architecture unmet dependency packages depending on GNU C Library: 32-bit development libraries for AMD64 (*libc6-dev-i386*). To correct the unmet dependencies, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Answer (score -2):

Try running this command:

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
```

This [attempts to fix broken dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do). (`--fix-broken` is the same as `-f`.)