# error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1:

Tags: 16.04, server, apt

I am having problem on this error **"error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: "** . so I install this package apt-get install zlib1g:i386 but this is th result.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8) but 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10 is to be installed
              Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Breaks: libssl-dev:i386 (!= 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8) but 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
 libssl-dev:i386 : Breaks: libssl-dev (!= 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> This is my operating system

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I tried apt-get -f install and this is the result

```
(Reading database ... 129365 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl-dev_1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h', which is different from other instances of package libssl-dev:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl-dev_1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: tried this? `Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages` ?

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy libssl-dev`. It seems that you have PPA or other third-party repository enabled.

Comment: +1 . . . specifically [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no question posted, I assume you want to move forward with `apt-get install zlib1g:i386`.

Do `sudo apt-get -f install`, similar to what was suggested.
That should fix your dependency system.

[What exactly does sudo apt-get -f install do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do)

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl-dev_1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h', which is different from other instances of package libssl-dev:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl-dev_1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)