# Error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, permissions, shared-library

I am trying to install  [TiddlyDesktop](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyDesktop). I have been following 
[this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-tiddlywiki-on-linux/)

I have downloaded the .zip file, unzipped it and then updated the file permissions like so:

```
sudo chmod +x nw
```

But, when I run the next command:

```
./nw
```

I get:

```
./nw: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) on SO and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992125/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz-so-1) but the `nw` file I am trying to execute really does exist in the folder so I am confused. And `sudo apt-get -f install` did not help either.

I only started using Ubuntu yesterday. I know the solution is probably going to be obvious for most users here but I just can't figure it out.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the missing library (in a terminal, ctrl-alt-t to start one):

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

That should fix your problem.  Shared libraries are needed by the executable, and are brought into the running process at load time.  You can see what shared libraries are needed by an executable with the ldd command

```
ldd nw
```