# Broken Packages/Unmet Dependecies

Tags: installation, 13.04, package-management

I have a problem. Since I upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, I've been receiving lots of errors, I can't install any program because it shows me a message that says (for this example I'll try to install Synaptic):

```
>alexis@McLovin:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
>Reading package lists... Done
>Building dependency tree       
>Reading state information... Done
>Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>or been moved out of Incoming.
>The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
>The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.12 (>= 1.0.9) but it is not installable
>            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not installable
>E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm new in Ubuntu, I hope it's not a dumb question.
Thank you(English is not my native language).

Comment: Please refer to this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/30994/44518

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or the one-liner:

```
sudo sh -c "dpkg --configure -a && apt-get install -f && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade"
```

Answer (score 0):

just one line worked for me ..

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

also .. i keep doing the following for no reason .. they might have been a factor in the solution

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

ps: the "install -f" removed skype from my system