# Problem with installing software

Tags: 13.04, wine

I tried to install wine from terminal i this is what i got:

```
liquid@liquid-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for liquid: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` should force the software to install its dependancies.

Comment: it says 0 upgraded, 0 installed 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying to install Wine, see if it solves the problem.

Comment: i get this: http://pastebin.com/yE6Ks1aD

Comment: try this, [Fixing Broken Packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-broken-packages)