# Unable to install any packages

Tags: apt

So I had a full /boot and I've really messed things up now. What I'd really like to do is run `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-{35,36,37,38}` but I need to fix these other problems first. So when I run `sudo apt-get -f install` this is what I get (I also get similar output for any other apt-get commands)

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-pae
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 192 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,726 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.41.49); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic-pae on system is 3.2.0.53.63.
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-headers-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.41.49); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic-pae on system is 3.2.0.53.63.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                       Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But this doesn't tell me enough what the other error was. I think it started when I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` with only about 20MB of free space in /boot. Grrr, /boot partition is super annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use Debian package management system - **dpkg**?

Simply remove old kernels with this commands:

```
# dpkg -P linux-image-3.2.0-{35,36,37,38}*
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/183625/7945

I needed to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` manually and remove the `linux-generic-pae` package, then I was able to run my purge command and then I was able to reinstall `linux-generic-pae`. I did `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic-pae` just to be sure.