# Deadlock-broken packages during Ubuntu 12.4 update: libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 and libjpeg-turbo8:i386

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, synaptic

**The problem**

I have not used my Ubuntu 12.4 (64 bit) netbook for about a year, and yesterday I tried to install one year worth of updates at once. The update did not go smoothly: I had to restart the netbook a few times because the Update Manager behaved strange.

Now I have about a half of the new packages installed, and I cannot go any further because I have two broken packages: `libjpeg-turbo8` and `libjpeg-turbo8:i386`.

I did not have any third-party repositories enabled, but the `Unsupported updates (precise-backports)` option had been enabled.

**What I have tried**

When I use `sudo apt-get install -f` I get an error message:

```
dpkg: error processing libjpeg-turbo8 (--configure): 
 libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1 cannot be configured because
 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 is in a different version (1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.3) 

dpkg: error processing libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (--configure): 
 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.3 cannot be configured because
 libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 is in a different version (1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1)
```

I looks like `libjpeg-turbo8:amd64` and `libjpeg-turbo8:i386` are in a deadlock: neither can be installed/configured because the other has a different version.

I cannot remove the broken packages, because too many other programs depend on them and would be removed too. The `Mark for upgrade` and `Mark for reinstallation` options in Synaptic do not work either. Neither does the `Force version...` menu.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8=1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.3` or `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8:i386=1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1` (You should do another update in the case of the latter command.)

Comment: Thank you very mach for your response! I have just solved the problem, so I will not be able to try your solution. Maybe, it will help to someone else. I'll post the solution that I used in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/183625/232323).

I have changed the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file manually, and removed two blocks: `libjpeg-turbo8:amd64` and `libjpeg-turbo8:i386`. Then I called `sudo apt-get install -f` and the problem was gone.